# PHP -SQL- UPDATE ISSUE

Tags: php, sql, datetime, sql-update, insert-update

I have got a problem. I am creating a patient registration system for my term project but i have a problem while controlling the dates. For example two people cannot make appointment at the same day. I wrote a query for it but it doesn't work. I have both `date(attributes:date,hour,status)` and `appointments(id,dept,date)` tables in my phpMyAdmin database. The status attribute is a boolean that controls the availability. If true, appointment can be done...
Here is my SQL query. Can you please help me?

```
$rquery="UPDATE date SET status='false'  WHERE date='$date'"; 
$resultr= mysql_query($rquery);

$date comes from appointment form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write '$date' because single quotes will interpret it literally, unlike double quotes that interpret it as a variable (more precisely, as a value of that variable). It will try to set the value of the date to $date (not to value stored in variable $date). Remove single quotes around $date and it should work.

Comment: I understand what you are meaning but again it doesn't work do you have any other sql query ideas for changing the status of selected date from true to false

Comment: @Misa But he enclosed the whole query in double quotes. Single quotes inside double-quoted string do not interfere with the way variables are expanded. These are needed so the SQL will contain a well formed clause.

Comment: @haep underrun Yes, but PHP is making a problem with them. If you really need them, then you should concatenate the strings. Like: $rquery="UPDATE date SET status='false' WHERE date='".$date."'";

Comment: @user2430445 How did you define a column "status" in table "date"? If it's a boolean, it should work with 'TRUE' and 'FALSE', or alternatively with 1 and 0.

Comment: yes I did and it is boolean I will try the capital letters now thank you

Comment: again it isn't working @MisaLazovic I will going to get mad cause this is the only problem in my whole code and if it won't work correctly on my presentation i will get a big 0. :(

Comment: @MisaLazovic the code that you submitted (@haep underrun Yes, but PHP is making a problem with them. If you really need them, then you should concatenate the strings. Like: $rquery="UPDATE date SET status='false' WHERE date='".$date."'"; –) works!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! :)

Comment: You're welcome :) The problem was not in capital letters, since sql is case insensitive. PHP was making a problem with quotes if you echo your query before executing it in rquery it will write out "UPDATE date SET status='false'  WHERE date=$date" and if you use concatenation, it will say UPDATE date SET status='false'  WHERE date='2013-05-29' or something like that